# Function reads iteration target as local argument string instead of iteration value in for loop

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, for-loop, crosstab

Trying to run this simple for loop with a pandas cross tab function. The iteration target is an argument in the cross-tab function. It's supposed to read through a list of columns and produce a cross-tab for each column combination. But instead it's interpreting my 'i' iterable as the literal title of the column instead of whatever variable it should be in that iteration.

I get the error: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'i' because it's reading 'i' as the literal name of an attribute instead of the value that should be stored in i from the loop.

```
import pandas



DF = pandas.read_excel('example.xlsx')

Categories = list(DF.columns.values)

for i in Categories:

    pandas.crosstab(DF.Q, DF.i, normalize = 'index', margins=True)
```

Comment: do `DF[i]` instead.

Comment: This worked thank you.

Comment: This should be answer

Answer (score 2):

IIUC, you want to loop though every column and create the cross tab against column `Q`, but your current loop won't produce anything.

Use the following to assign the results to a python `dict` that you can access with column names as the key:

```
DF = pandas.read_excel('example.xlsx')

Categories = list(DF.columns.values)

cross_tabs = {}

for i in Categories:
    cross_tabs[i] = pandas.crosstab(DF.Q, DF[i], normalize = 'index', margins=True)
```

Comment: Useful input but not exactly a solution to the problem. See Quang Hoang comment above for answer. Thank you though. I will consider the usefulness of putting into dict.

Comment: @MichaelHavlin apologies buddy